# Queued Laravel jobs all fire simultaneously, and don't show up in the jobs table

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks

I am using Laravel queues for commenting on Facebook posts. Whenever I receive data from a Facebook webhook, based on the received details I comment on the post. To handle 100 responses at once from Facebook webhooks, I am using Laravel queues, so that it can execute one by one.
I used the step by step process as mentioned in [Why Laravel Queues Are Awesome](https://scotch.io/tutorials/why-laravel-queues-are-awesome)

```
public function webhooks(Request $request)
{
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    Log::info("Request Cycle with Queues Begins");
    $job = (new webhookQueue($data)->delay(10);
    $this->dispatch($job);
    Log::info("Request Cycle with Queues Ends");
}
```

and this is my job class structure

```
class webhookQueue extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{    
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    private $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
       //handling the data here 
    }
}
```

I am hitting the `webhooks()` function continuously, and all the jobs are working simultaneously but not in the queue. None of the jobs are being stored in the jobs table. I have given a delay but it is also not working.

And this is my laravel.log:

```
[2017-02-08 14:18:42] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Begins  
[2017-02-08 14:18:44] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Begins  
[2017-02-08 14:18:47] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Begins  
[2017-02-08 14:18:47] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Begins  
[2017-02-08 14:18:47] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Begins  
[2017-02-08 14:18:47] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Begins  
[2017-02-08 14:18:48] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Begins  
[2017-02-08 14:18:48] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Begins  
[2017-02-08 14:18:48] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Begins  
[2017-02-08 14:18:48] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Begins  
[2017-02-08 14:18:48] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Begins  
[2017-02-08 14:18:48] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Begins  
[2017-02-08 14:18:55] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Ends  
[2017-02-08 14:18:55] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Ends  
[2017-02-08 14:18:55] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Ends  
[2017-02-08 14:18:59] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Ends  
[2017-02-08 14:19:00] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Ends  
[2017-02-08 14:19:00] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Ends  
[2017-02-08 14:19:00] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Ends  
[2017-02-08 14:19:01] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Ends  
[2017-02-08 14:19:01] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Ends  
[2017-02-08 14:19:01] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Ends  
[2017-02-08 14:19:01] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Ends  
[2017-02-08 14:19:01] local.INFO: Request Cycle with Queues Ends
```

Comment: Database queue did not work for me because it sent to different channel

Answer (score 53, accepted):

for use queue you should some work :

in .env file you should change QUEUE_DRIVER or QUEUE_CONNECTION (newer versions) from sync to database,
so open .env and do the follow

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

or

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

after it you should create queue table in your database with artisan command :

```
php artisan queue:table
php artisan migrate
```

and for make sure that no config cached

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and finally you should run your queue with `php artisan queue:listen` or `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: Yes, i have done this, after php artisan:listen command, while data is processing, nothing is coming in cmd prompt

Comment: i have got the solution, i didnt change queue_drive to database, thank you for replying.

Comment: @Mahdi - Hey, the command should be `php artisan queue:listen` not `php artisan:listen`

Comment: i fix typo issue ... sorry for that .. @TipuZaynSultan

Comment: if your problem solve , mark this as solution of your question @TipuZaynSultan

Comment: Interestingly, I had it set to `database` and had to change it back to `sync` to make this work. Thanks for the right hint!

Comment: `queue:listen` and `queue:work` are just processing one queue item but I have 20 queue items in the database and more getting stacked. @MahdiYouseftabar

Comment: @AnkitJindal i think you issue is inrevlevent to this issue ! you can ask it in an another question

Comment: Just info, for the newer Laravel version (I don't know which version has this applied, but I am using v7.23.2), `QUEUE_DRIVER` has changed to `QUEUE_CONNECTION` in the `.env` file

Comment: I was not generating this queue table. also needed to run php artisan config:cache. thanks a lot

Comment: @ImranHossain you should run config:clear instead of config:cache! new users will have more issue when they ran config cache

Answer (score 40):

I had the same trouble, if you are using **`Laravel 5.7 or above`**, use this in .env file

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

Next, clear config cache like this

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: I had the same when function can't delay() because artisan cache.
So clear artisan cache to resolved.

Comment: This helped me. Many blog articles doesn't say that you must clear cache after some config changes.

Comment: if you never run the config cache command it will never cache the config, which is what you should do in dev (never run config cache)

Comment: My queue was not running because of this. thanks a  lot

Answer (score 17):

In my case, i use custom queue name for group my jobs.

```
ProcessCourseInteractions::dispatch($courseProcessing)->onQueue('course_interactions');
```

That queue is not executed by:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

and

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

i need specify queue name (Valid for work and listen):

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=course_interactions
```

Comment: It's working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Update for Laravel 5.7:

In `.env`, set `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` so that dispatched jobs go to the database driver.

Then:

```
 # Creates a migration for the database table holding the jobs
php artisan queue:table

 # Executes the migration
php artisan migrate

 # Kicks off the process that executes jobs when they are dispatched
php artisan queue:work
```

Comment: This also applies for redis - found in newer Laravel / Horizon that QUEUE_DRIVER wasn't enough. 2 hours lost! Thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

Make sure your app is not in maintenance mode... I had mine in maintenance, but allowing my local ip address... I couldn't figure out why it was not running. I had to finally go debugging the WorkCommand to find out...

./artisan up;

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer was a problem for me, but I also wound up on this question for 2 other similar problems which I solved, and maybe they will help other people that wind up here.

**Other problem 1**: job creation (constructor) works, but job handler does not fire - **ever**.

- the **ever** is key here because, typically, if none of them ever fire, then it could be because your job code is modified and your queue should be restarted.

**Other problem 2**: job creation (constructor) works, but job handler does not fire - **sometimes**.

- when **sometimes** is true for you, then it may be that your jobs that are not firing are because they are happening while in a transaction, like a `DB::beginTransaction`.

Assuming I *want* the job to fire even during a transaction, I can do this:

```
/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($errorInfo)
{
    $this->errorInfo = $errorInfo;

    // Queues won't run the handlers during transactions
    // so, detect the level, and if it is not 0, rollback to force job handling
    if (\DB::transactionLevel() != 0) {
        \DB::rollBack();
    }
}
```

**BUT DON'T DO THIS** unless you *want* to fire your job and force rollback. My situation is unique in that my job sends emails on FATAL errors, so I want it to fire because I have an error breaking the process anyway (rollback going to happen and is unplanned due to uncaught error).

Here's a situation when you wouldn't want to do this:

- your job sends an email to a user when payment is successful
- your payment could be successful, could not be
- depending on successful payment, you rollback or commit

You should structure your dispatch to happen AFTER you rollback or commit. 
I did not have that luxury for my job because it happens when I cannot predict (a FATAL error). But if you have control over it, like knowing your payment is successful, dispatch after you have committed, or exited all levels of transactions!

I am not sure of the behavior of triggering a job while in the transaction, and *then* rolling back or committing. It could be worked around if it didn't work properly by adding a delay, but that seems unreliable (guessing at how long to wait) unless it was a significant delay.

Comment: Thank you. you have saved my half an hour

Comment: Yes In my case everything was correct Except I was not restarting the queue worker 
after the changes.

1) "php artisan queue:work" 
or
2) php artisan queue:restart

Answer (score 3):

### Set `.env`

- `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`

### Add Migrations

- `php artisan queue:table`
- `php artisan migrate`

#### If you use

- `dispatch(new YourJob($order))->onQueue('queue_name')`

### Finally Run This Command

- `php artisan queue:work --queue=queue_name`

Answer (score 2):

I am seeing that you already have Queue table.

Try running `php artisan queue:listen --tries=3` or `php artisan queue:work` etc.

Queue work is for executing only one Job per command. So if there are 20 jobs in the table you might have to run queue work 20 times. That's why you can run `queue:listen` command. But it eats up a lot of CPU.

In the server, you might want to run your queue listen with max 3 tries in the background.
SSH to your server in the Terminal / Command Prompt. Then `CD` to your project directory where the artisan file lives. Run this command:

`nohup php artisan queue:listen --tries=3 > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

In this case jobs will automatically be processed in the background. You just have to dispatch the job. And I would recommend using failed-jobs table. If you are using background queue listner.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for replying, i have got the solution, i didnt change queue_drive to database

Answer (score 1):

For future readers of that questions , if queues were working before but no longer , just try to delete everything from the jobs table in the database , that worked for me .

Answer (score 1):

Don't make the same mistake as me,

I was running `php artisan queue:work` in the wrong directory.

Only wasted 30 minutes, could have been longer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` in .env file

Answer (score 0):

All thing are set-up and still not work then make sure added schedule on crontab -e
`* * * * * cd /var/www/html/<project_name> && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try again in the following way (I assume that you did instructions in Laravel docs but someday it's not working):

Step 1: drop table 'jobs' in your database.

Step 2: run command 'php artisan migrate' in console to create table 'jobs' again.

Step 3: run command 'php artisan queue:work' in console

Step 4: retry your app

Note that in .env file, you set up:

QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

QUEUE_DRIVER=database

P/s: It works for me!